# Postgres tuning max_connections

Tags: python, postgresql, performance, config

I have a multi-threaded process whereby 36 threads write to the db randomly, each once every 10s on average, each with 99% idle time (sleeping).

I am not sure if this means I have 36 active connections, or effectively just one or two because of the sleep in each thread. Probably not relevant but they all use the same username.

Should I reduce the max-connections option in the config file to 36 or to something small like 4 (to reflect the probability that at any instant in time, almost certainly not more than 4 are simultaneously writing)?

Edit: is it possible that its implementation dependent, i.e. how I wrote my python code whether the connections are dropped while sleeping or not?

Answer (score 2):

the neatest set here would be using pgbouncer for connection pooling:
https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html

`default_pool_size = 4` would keep 4 permanent connections to the postgres, pooling your 36 to use one of four when session completes.

I'm recommending pooler, because whether the connection persists on server or not depends on whether you disconnect or not. also zombies would keep a connection, while your code would initiate new sessions.

in short - to run query you have to connect to a database as user. If you run on same session another transaction, you reuse the connection (if you did not disconnect). You have to explicitly disconnect to close the session. If you fail to do it, connection will stay on server (using one of `max_connections` slots.

also from 9.6 on we have `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`, which kills transaction if its idla for longer then n period, which would help to fight against zombies.